# actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript

I have a picture sliding on my scene, with fade  in and out pictures between frames 1 and 100. I would like to create 2 buttons that could go to previous picture and next picture and I just can figure out the code. Need help pls. I tryed like this on last frame, 2 ways:

```
gotoAndPlay(1);

btnA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backward);
btnB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, forward);

function backward(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if(this.currentFrame == (1, 30))
    {
        gotoAndPlay(66);
    }
    else
    {
        gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
}

function forward(event:MouseEvent)
{
    if(this.currentFrame == 1, 30)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(31);
    }
    if(this.currentFrame == 31, 65)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(66);
    }
    if(this.currentFrame == 66, 100)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: replace if(this.currentFrame == 1, 30) with  if(this.currentFrame >= 1  && this.currentFrame <= 30).....

Answer (score 0):

for all statements you should do:

```
...
if(event.target.currentFrame == 1  ||  event.target.currentFrame == 30)
    {
        gotoAndPlay(31);
    }
....
```

Comment: What is the newest version of Flash out there. I have not used it in a couple of years (5 or so) and I want to use the newest version for developing some parts of a web page. Also what is better HTML 5 or using Flash?

Comment: @user3376708 the flash version doesn't matter right, what matter is the actionscript which is always AS3, I think you d'better use HTML5 instead, everyone is moving to HTML5 it's the Future